# Use CSS defined font face in imported SVGs

Tags: css, svg

Is it possible to set `@font-face` rules for SVG that are assets (as opposed to embedded SVGs)?

I know you can set the styles in the SVG's `<defs>`, but I'm talking about setting them in your CSS file.

I have hundreds of SVG images that all have something like:

```
<text id="Text" font-family="SlatePro-Bk"</text>
```

I have the `SlatePro-Bk` defined in my CSS, the SVGs don't pick it up.

I have tried to no avail:

```
svg {
  font-family: 'SlatePro-Bk';
}
```

Font face rule in my CSS is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SlatePro-Bk';
    src:  url('../fonts/slatePro-bk.eot') format('eot'),
          url('../fonts/slatePro-bk.otf') format('otf'),
          url('../fonts/slatePro-bk.woff2') format('woff2'),
          url('../fonts/slatePro-bk.woff') format('woff');  
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you linking your SVGs to your CSS and what does your @font-face configuration look like?

Comment: The SVGs are mostly background images, some are inline images. I updated the question with the font-face rules. Thanks!

Comment: You still haven't answered my first question. How are you linking your SVGs to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

I Paul,
to include a font in SVG you have to declare it not only in your css, but also into your SVG element.

In your SVG element you can put:

```
    <font id="Font1" horiz-adv-x="1000">
  <font-face font-family="Super Sans" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal"
      units-per-em="1000" cap-height="600" x-height="400"
      ascent="700" descent="300"
      alphabetic="0" mathematical="350" ideographic="400" hanging="500">
    <font-face-src>
      <font-face-name name="Super Sans Bold"/>
    </font-face-src>
  </font-face>
  <missing-glyph><path d="M0,0h200v200h-200z"/></missing-glyph>
  <glyph unicode="!" horiz-adv-x="300"><!-- Outline of exclam. pt. glyph --></glyph>
  <glyph unicode="@"><!-- Outline of @ glyph --></glyph>
  <!-- more glyphs -->
</font>
```

Hope it helps!

Katia

Answer (score 0):

Font assets have to be Base64 encoded and embedded within the SVG file to work cross browser. I created a tool that will scan the file and embed the appropriate assets.

https://github.com/BTBurke/svg-embed-font

Let me know if that helps.